# Return vales from jQuery dialog box that is dynamically created

Tags: jquery, vb.net

I have the Following code which displays a jQuery dialog box with some fields, a save button and a cancel button.

The dialog shows, no poblem. You can enter text in to the fields.

But how do I get the values back to my VB.net MVC code? Thanks.

```
enter code here<script type="text/javascript">
var $dialog;
var $currentForm;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $dialog = $('<div></div>')
        .html('<fieldset><ol>' +
            '<select>' +
            '<option value="CONTAINS">contains</option>' +
            '<option value="NOTCONTAINS">does not contain</option>' +
            '<option value="EQUAL">equals</option>' +
            '<option value="NOTEQUAL">does not equal</option>' +
            '<option value="GT">is greater than</option>' +
            '<option value="LT">is less than</option>' +
        '</select>' +
        '<li>' +
            '<form action="/" id="condition"><input type="text" id="con" name="con"/>' +
            '<input class="enterCondition" type="submit" value="Save Condition" /></form>' +
        '</li>' +
    '</ol>' +
'</fieldset>' +
'<p>Press Escape to cancel input.</p>')
        .dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            buttons: {
                'Save Condition': function () {
                    alert($(this));
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                },
                'Cancel': function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            },
            modal: true,
            closeOnEscape: true,
            width: 520,
            resizable: false,
            title: "Generator Conditions",
            show: { effect: "fade", speed: "slow" },
            hide: { effect: "fade", speed: "slow" }
        });

    $('#enterCondition').click(function () {
        $currentForm = $(this).closest('Form')
        $dialog.dialog('open');
        return false; ////cancel eventbubbeling
    });

    function ShowResult(result) {
        alert(result);
    }
});

function showDialog() {
    $dialog.dialog('open');
    return false //cancel eventbubbeling
}
```

Its produced the jQuery popup dialog box no problem, but how do I get the values back to the VB.Net view/form?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to use `ajax` functionality to post the data to a script on the server that can process it.

Comment: It is the only way to go, so +1.
You can eventually redirect to a specific url with get parameters... but it could be a big mess. Send you datas with POST method via AJAX: it's clean.

Comment: Thanks Mike. Used $.post() and all is well....Im on a steep curve. Thankls again...